# Adding things like `fromPromise` from rxjs doesn't work in webpack 4

Tags: angular, webpack, rxjs, webpack-4, rxjs6

I've tried countless times upgrading to webpack 4 in one of our big projects, but each time I do I end up getting multiple errors, which I tracked back to rxjs. I haven't opened this issue until after I read so many similar looking problems, but none resolved my issue, and I'm still confused as to why this is happening in the first place.

In someplace, I do:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

// Use Observable.fromPromise()
```

In `vendor.ts`, which is an entry module that I use to import things, I do this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
```

Please note that this worked completely fine with webpack 3. Only after I update to webpack 4 do I get the problem. Furthermore, if I import from `rxjs/Rx` instead, this particular problem seems to be fixed, which means it's a problem related to `fromPromise` not being imported.

I had the following webpack config before I updated, in webpack 3:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  names: ['vendor', 'polyfills'],
}),
```

I have this after the update, in webpack 4:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            vendor: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name: 'vendor',
                chunks: 'all',
            },
        },
    },
},
```

**Environment**

- Runtime: all major browsers
- RxJS version: 6.2.2
- Webpack: 4.16.3 (and all versions of webpack 4)

[image]

Comment: rxjs 6 use from instead

Comment: I can't see this mentioned in the migration guide, and it works fine in webpack 3, also I can see the definition in rxjs 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering a lot with webpack, it seems to be working now. I have no idea what was wrong, maybe it's just a change in webpack 4. But one important thing is to use `from` instead of `fromPromise` if you're using the latest rxjs package.